# How to know when PayPal recurring payment fired?

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I'm using new PayPal REST API to manage users recurring payments. When i create recurring profile i provide `return_url` and `cancel_url`. But how do i know if scheduled payment succeeded or failed so i can prolong or cancel user profile in my application? I know there is IPN but it should be used with old Classic API.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  It will allow you to automate tasks based on all sorts of transactions on your account, including new subscription profiles and payments related to them.

Comment: I tried IPN and it does not work with REST API. I see the record that client was billed but there is no records in my merchant IPN history. Why?

Comment: Do you have it enabled and active in your PayPal profile?

Comment: Sure. I've provided IPN url and enabled it.

Comment: So, what can you say? Have you tried it for yourself?

Comment: I have not tried it myself, no.  I was under the impression that any transaction done in a PayPal account would trigger an IPN, but that apparently may not be correct.  I have yet to start using PayPal's REST API because it's so far behind the classic API's.  This may be another example of a feature it's missing.  I would recommend posting a ticket to [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts) to confirm.